# Gatsby changing layout programmatically

Tags: gatsby

Starting to use Gatsby (v2), I was wondering what could be the best way to handle a scenario as visible on Behance website which is the following one :

- If I access a certain URL directly from address bar, a template (A) with is own layout will be displayed
- If I access the same URL from a Link on the website, the page will be displayed with another template (B)

Is there any way to define a `Layout` at runtime ? The 2 scenario bring to the exact same URL.

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the perfect example you could look into is:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/gatsbygram

At `gatsby-browser.js` it sets this function:

```
exports.onInitialClientRender = () => {
  window.___GATSBYGRAM_INITIAL_RENDER_COMPLETE = true
}
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onInitialClientRender

And then sets in `src/templates/post-page.js` the `isModal` depending on exactly what you described in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for